# Hard instances in Impagliazzo's Heuristica

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, average-case-complexity

In Impagliazzo's imaginary world Heuristica, P ≠ NP but all NP problems are easy on average for any samplable probability distribution.

In [Impagliazzo's paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/SCT.1995.514853), he implies that if you do manage to find a hard instance in Heuristica, it won't take much more effort to solve the instance than it took to find the instance in the first place.

> In 
>   this 
>   world, 
>   Grouse 
>   might 
>   be 
>   able 
>   to 
>   find 
>   problems 
>   that 
>   Gauss 
>   cannot 
>   answer 
>   in  class, 
>   but 
>   it 
>   might 
>   take 
>   Grouse 
>   a 
>   week 
>   to 
>   find 
>   a  problem 
>   that 
>   Gauss 
>   could 
>   not 
>   solve 
>   in 
>   a 
>   day, 
>   and 
>   a 
>   year 
>   to 
>   find 
>   one 
>   that 
>   Gauss 
>   could 
>   not 
>   solve 
>   in 
>   a 
>   month. 
>   (Here, 
>   I 
>   am 
>   assuming 
>   that 
>   Gauss 
>   has 
>   some polynomial 
>   advantage 
>   over 
>   Grouse, 
>   since 
>   Gauss 
>   is 
>   after 
>   all 
>   a 
>   genius!) 
>   Presumably,  “real-life” 
>   is 
>   not 
>   so 
>   adversarial 
>   that 
>   it 
>   would 
>   solve 
>   intractable 
>   problems 
>   just 
>   to 
>   give  us 
>   a 
>   hard 
>   time, 
>   so 
>   for  all 
>   practical 
>   purposes 
>   this 
>   world 
>   is  indistinguishable  from 
>   Algorithmica.

However, what I'm not clear on is whether the following scenario is possible: It takes time 1.001<sup>*n*</sup> to find a 3-SAT instance that takes time 1.3<sup>*n*</sup> to solve.  In other words, Grouse can still maintain an exponential advantage over Gauss provided that Grouse is prepared to invest an exponential amount of work.

Is there a simple argument (or if not, is there a standard complexity hypothesis) that implies that this can't happen in Heuristica?